# .bzl file in external dependencies

Tags: bazel

I've an external dependency declared in WORKSPACE as a `new_git_repository` and provided a BUILD file for it.

```
proj/
├── BUILD
├── external
│   ├── BUILD.myDep
│   └── code.bzl
└── WORKSPACE
```

in the `BUILD.myDep` file, I want to load `code.bzl` nearby, but when I load it (`load("//:external/code.bzl", "some_func")`) bazel tries to load `@myDep//:external/code.bzl` instead!
Of course it's not a target in `@myDep` repository, but in my local worksapce.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I *Rubber Duck* ed the Stackoverflow. since the solution appeared when writing the question!
However, the solution is to explicitly mention the local workspace when loading the `.bzl` file:
Suppose we have declared the name in the `WORKSPACE` as below:

```py
workspace(name = "local_proj")
```

Now instead of `load("//:external/code.bzl", "some_func")`, just load it explicitly as a local workspace file:

```py
load("@local_proj//:external/code.bzl", "some_func")
```

**NOTE**: When using this trick just be careful about potential dependency loops (i.e. loading a generated file that itself is produced by a rule depending on the same external repo!)